# Galaxy Note Layout Issue

Tags: java, android, layout, screen, galaxy

I'm developing a software but now I have a problem with Galaxy Note. How can I emulate actual size of Galaxy Note in emulator? 
I put my resources in folder names: layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800.
But when I run my program in emulator I see that widgets are not in proper position. That's not what I designed. is some tutorials i see that users talking about Scale!! but i cant find anywhere that i set the scale... please help me :)

My emulator config:

```
resolution: 800*1280
density:285
```

Comment: Have you set the density of the emulator as HDPI?

Comment: @Kai: i dont see any option in my emulator for HDPI. there is only "Abstracted LCD density" and i set it to 285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your galaxy note ???

This is what you will see on the original Galaxy Note (shipped with Gingerbread)

```
Screen pixel density (dpi) - xhdpi
Screen size - large
Screen aspect - long
Most of the other tablets (7 inch and 10.1 inch tablets) are mdpi.
```

This device will pick values from the large resource category since size takes precedence over density.

After the ICS update, the device classifies itself as below.

```
Screen pixel density (dpi) - xhdpi
Screen size - normal
Screen aspect - not long
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the answer on stackoverflow.

Check the following thread :
[Samsung Galaxy Note emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221680/samsung-galaxy-note-emulator)

The answer from Rajesh is really good. He gives you a link to download a Galaxy Note Skin for android emulator. With that you will be able to create easily a Galaxy Note emulator.

Hope it helps you.