# Samsung Galaxy Note emulator

Tags: android, emulation, galaxy

I am trying to create emulator for Samsung Galaxy Note. But it is not working.

I tried the following config

- sdk r17
- platform 2.3.3
- resolution 1280x800
- density 320

Emulator skin is comeup. But it doesn't have any navigation keys (menu, back and home keys). Also no keyboard displayed.

I also tried with platform 4.0.3. Same problem there. Emulator comes up without any keys.

For Galaxy Tab I use Samsung addon. So no problem with emulator.
But I couldn't' find any addon for Galaxy Note.

Comment: Did u gie any resolution as default value as 1280*800? if so it will come without keys only.This will occur in normal emulator for me. just select the built in resolution while creating emulator through avd manager.

Answer (score 24):

I have created a Galaxy Note AVD skin, which you can download from [GitHub](https://github.com/rayesh/android-emulator-skins/) ([direct download](https://github.com/downloads/rayesh/android-emulator-skins/Galaxy%20Note.zip)) with credits to Heiko Behrens, whose [article](http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/) you can refer to understand how to use it.

In short, you can simply extract the zip file to the **< PathToAndroidSDK >/platforms/android-X/skins/** directory (were X is the API level of the SDK you want to use - in case of 2.3.3, it would be 10). You can then create the AVD from a freshly started AVD manager which will show "Galaxy Note" skin for that API level.

Comment: I am not able to use my system keyboard to enter text in the emulator.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812241/1321873 also

Comment: It's working after adding keyboard support for emulator. Thanks for your Galaxy Note AVD.

Comment: I get lots of OutOfMemoryErrors when I try to use this skin. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you get OOM in your android app or while starting the emulator?

Comment: @Rajesh am also getting a lot of OutOfmemory when I use this not skin. ANy ideas to solve it? But other than that its cool.

Comment: Try increasing the VM application heap and RAM sizes.

Comment: Looks like they have changed the way skins work. Shall check and update the post when there is a workable solution.

Comment: it still picks the resource from layout not from layout-large

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to update the skin. Shall mention you in a comment as soon as the update is available.

Comment: OK, thanks. Also, do you know what all needs to be done for the skin to work with new ADT? Could you tell me that also when you can?

Answer (score 4):

Hi user1123931 while creating AVD in eclipse there is an option in Hardware section -> New-> Keyboard Support. select it while creating or editing you device. The keyboard should be visible now.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are specially developed skins to provide those UI elements in the Emulator.
You can also use the special keyboard shortcuts in replacement of those UI buttons:
[Android Emulator Shortcut Keys](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling)